# Adding custom stickers in Gboard for iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, gboard

I have created an Android sticker application which is searchable in Android Gboard, with help of nice tutorial provided [here](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-create-your-own-sticker-pack-for-google-keyboard-demo-e6ef7f9df31f) and firebase app indexing.

**My question here is how to achieve same for Gboard for IOS?** I have not found any resource for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Magic Emoji" on iOS,
Magic Emoji is the Gboard emoji kitchen for iOS & iMessage.
AppStore search "Magic Emoji" and have a try.
hope you like it.

[app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooZQv.png)